# Image is not showing in next and react?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, nextjs-image

I have data fetched from API and I want to display an image with Next and React but I can't see the image appear in the screen the alt for the image just showing. I am using next/image instead of HTML img?

this is the imaeUrl coming from API `181fc194-ca2c-4f11-8442-4d52c094491f.jpg` ,

I add this to fix the path but still showing the alt of the image
 `` const image = `/${course.imageUrl}` ``

```
 <Image
          src={image}
          alt="Picture of the author"
          width={500}
          height={500}
        />
```

any ideas what I should di to fix that?

Comment: Have you tried doing it with a HTML element `<img>` using the path to check if the image is even being fetched?

Comment: And also, can you display  the image alone through `[Your app URL]/181fc194-ca2c-4f11-8442-4d52c094491f.jpg` in your browser ?

Comment: I try with html img and give me the same result, should I add my app URL before the image like what you have done to be shown?

Comment: It's coming from this api https://api.tabasher.dev/api/services/app/Curriculums/GetCourseCurriculumByCode?code=cook

Comment: I just take the imageUrl and try to display it

Comment: That's the API response, but where is the image itself being served from? What does the full URL for an image look like?

Comment: I think this is what you mean https://tabasher-dev-storage.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/181fc194-ca2c-4f11-8442-4d52c094491f.jpg

Comment: I add this before the imageUrl and it's appear, but not sure if this is the only way to fix that?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Did you [configure the images domain](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#domains) in your `next.config.js`? But yeah, you need to provide the full URL for the image for it to display, unless you have a custom loader set.

Comment: What is loader using for, I am new for using next can you explain that please, also what is the correct domain I should I add in the ```next.config.js``` to be working?

Comment: I add this now ```https://tabasher-dev-storage.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/${course.imageUrl}` ``` and I see the image using html img but not working with Next Image